# Strip phpbb bbcode

Tags: php, regex, phpbb, phpbb3

I want to display the most recent posts from my phpbb3 forum on my website, but without the bbcode.
so I'm trying to strip the bbcode but without succes
one of the posts for example could be:

```
[quote="SimonLeBon":3pwalcod]bladie bla bla[/quote:3pwalcod]bla bla bladie bla blaffsd
fsdjhgfd dgfgdffgdfg
```

to strip bbcodes i use the function i found via google, I've tried several other similiar functions aswell:

```
 <?php
function stripBBCode($text_to_search) {
     $pattern = '|[[\/\!]*?[^\[\]]*?]|si';
     $replace = '';
     return preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $text_to_search);
}
?>
```

This however doesn't really have any effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the one from phpBB (slightly adjusted to be standalone):

```
/**
* Strips all bbcode from a text and returns the plain content
*/
function strip_bbcode(&$text, $uid = '')
{
    if (!$uid)
    {
        $uid = '[0-9a-z]{5,}';
    }

    $text = preg_replace("#\[\/?[a-z0-9\*\+\-]+(?:=(?:&quot;.*&quot;|[^\]]*))?(?::[a-z])?(\:$uid)\]#", ' ', $text);

    $match = return array(
        '#<!\-\- e \-\-><a href="mailto:(.*?)">.*?</a><!\-\- e \-\->#',
        '#<!\-\- l \-\-><a (?:class="[\w-]+" )?href="(.*?)(?:(&amp;|\?)sid=[0-9a-f]{32})?">.*?</a><!\-\- l \-\->#',
        '#<!\-\- ([mw]) \-\-><a (?:class="[\w-]+" )?href="(.*?)">.*?</a><!\-\- \1 \-\->#',
        '#<!\-\- s(.*?) \-\-><img src="\{SMILIES_PATH\}\/.*? \/><!\-\- s\1 \-\->#',
        '#<!\-\- .*? \-\->#s',
        '#<.*?>#s',
    );
    $replace = array('\1', '\1', '\2', '\1', '', '');

    $text = preg_replace($match, $replace, $text);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This will strip bbcode, that is valid (i.e. opening tags matching closing tags).

```
$str = preg_replace('/\[(\w+)=.*?:(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/\1:\2\]/', '$3', $str);
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/JoqRBD).

#### Reusable Function

```
function stripBBCode($str) {
   return preg_replace('/\[(\w+)=.*?:(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/\1:\2\]/', '$3', $str);
}
```

#### Explanation

1. `\[` match literal `[`.
2. `(\w+)` Match 1 or more word characters and save in capturing group `1`.
3. `=` Match literal `=`.
4. `.*?` Match ungreedily every character except `\n` between `=` and `:`.
5. `:` Match literal `:`.
6. `(.*?)` Match ungreedily every character except `\n` between `:` and `]` and save in capturing group `2`.
7. `\]` Match literal `]`.
8. `(.*?)` Match ungreedily every character except `\n` between `:` and `]` and save in capturing group `3`.
9. `\[` Match literal `[`.
10. `/\1\2` Match previous capturing groups again.
11. `\]` Match literal `]`.

Comment: The term I mostly commonly see for "ungreedy" is "parsimonious."

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the BBCode parsing facilities that are built in to PHP?

http://php.net/manual/en/book.bbcode.php

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, use phpbb's own function https://wiki.phpbb.com/Strip_bbcode